# Social media icons for Simple Blogger Template

Tags: blogs, blogger

[image]

I need to add above mentioned social media icons into my blog. Currently I did it by using each and every page.So now I need to change the Simple Blogger template to add it once and appear it for all the articles.So how can I do that ? Which sections of blogging template should I change ? This should appears after the heading.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Blogger Dashboard > Template > Edit HTML.
Search for `<data:post.body/>` and paste your sharing buttons code just above it > Save your template > Done